# Java - having buttons displaying arrows

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, arrow-keys

I would like to have a buttons in Java which shows the arrows - like on the keyboard.
So far I have this

```
JButton arrowUp = new JButton("^");
JButton arrowDown = new JButton("v");
JButton arrowLeft = new JButton("<");
JButton arrowRight = new JButton(">");
```

It kinda works ... but does not look quite nice.

Any help how to improve this is appreciated

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Swing has a default arrow button class that is [`BasicArrowButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicArrowButton.html)

Example:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Arrow Button Demo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.EAST), BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.add(new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.NORTH), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.SOUTH), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.add(new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.WEST), BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 11):

Using an [ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) on the button, or one of the Swing [BasicArrowButtons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicArrowButton.html) is probably the best approach. However, you *could* also use Unicode arrow symbols. For example

`\u25C4`: ◄

`\u2190`: ←

`\u25BA`: ►

`\u2192`: →

Some resources:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_%28symbol%29
- http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/arrows.html
- [Unicode symbols (arrows) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2183098/127035)

You would need to ensure that the font(s) your application may use supports these symbols.

Comment: This is good solution indeed, but I will probably go for BasicArrowButtons. Anyways thanks for it!

Answer (score 4):

Just use a image:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/icon.gif");
JButton button2 = new JButton(icon);
```

Comment: If I build the application to .JAR file and send to my friend ... will he see the icons?

Comment: @PavelJanicek: If you include icons in jar and properly get them as resources in your class then *YES*.