# Eclipe - handling accents in java file

Tags: java, eclipse, utf-8, internationalization, eclipse-jdt

Comments in java file are written in french. However the code is getting distorted. What setting in eclipse can i use so that code and comment  is rendered properly.

```
// R�cup�ration des params d'envoi mail du fichier BFC2.properties

texte.append("Vous recevez ce mail automatique suite � la cr�ation d�un ou plusieurs nouveaux items dans");
        texte.append("l�application FERIA");
```

Comment: try setting, `Window > Preferences > General > Content Types`, set `UTF-8` as the default encoding, also refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167880/eclipseusing-utf-8-encoding-in-the-text-editor-make-the-strings-not-work-proper) discussion

Comment: You can use unicode escapes, but it's hard to tell which you need because your text doesn't render here.

Comment: it does not work with this setting.. i have tried it

Comment: If you did not create these files you need to find out what encoding was used to create them

Answer (score 0):

I really hope this is a university project.
Anyway, I am guessing you're using Windows which means that default character encoding for your source files will be Windows-1252 (since it's French).
What you need is to change file encoding both on project level and individual file level.

First you need to select current project, right-click on it and select `Properties` from a pop-up menu:

[image]

Then you can set global file encoding for the project:

[image]

This should set valid encoding for new folders and files. However, it won't change encoding of existing ones. In order to change the encoding for the file, you need to right click on it and select its properties:

[image]

Only then you can actually change the encoding for your current file:

[image]

Your job is sadly still not over, since now you'd have to fix broken accents by hand. Sorry.
The better option is to actually use `ResourceBundles` - you can read more about this approach [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html). This is easily done via Eclipse built-in string externationalization feature (`Source` -> `Externalize Strings...`).