# Insert cyrillic symbols into an XML file using Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I am consider an example from here: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0625.html

We have an XML file:

```
<data>
 <employee>
    <name>John</name>
    <title>Manager</title>
 </employee>
 <employee>
    <name>Sara</name>
    <title>Clerk</title>
 </employee>
</data>
```

We use this Java app:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class XMLReplaceDemo {
  static String inputFile = "C:/temp/data.xml";
  static String outputFile = "C:/temp/data_new.xml";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
        .newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(inputFile));

    // locate the node(s)
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xpath.evaluate
        ("//employee/name[text()='John']", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    // make the change
    for (int idx = 0; idx < nodes.getLength(); idx++) {
      nodes.item(idx).setTextContent("John Paul");
    }

    // save the result
    Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    xformer.transform
        (new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(new File(outputFile)));
  }
}
```

to change `<name>John</name>` to `<name>John Paul</name>`.

The example works perfectly for Latin symbols, digits, punctuation marks, but it returns a bunch of unreadable characters if I attempt to replace the original value with the one written in cyrillic symbols.

So the question is: is there any way to modify the Java code to make it work as I need it to?

I am a novice in Java.

Comment: Consider saving your Java source files as UTF-8 if you need to work with string literals that contain characters outside of the ANSI range. Here are two related posts: [Should source code be saved in UTF-8 format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178348/should-source-code-be-saved-in-utf-8-format), [How to compile a java source file which is encoded as “UTF-8”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726174/how-to-compile-a-java-source-file-which-is-encoded-as-utf-8)

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks, encoding when compiling helped.

Comment: If you could wrap up what you did in an answer of your own, that would be perfect.